# HTML/AngularJS - How can I make the first name, last name, and email of this editable?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

This is a code snippet from the E-Com site we use, I do not have access to the JS, only HTML and CSS.  Most of the fields need to be read only so they can only be updated from the address book.  But all the fields are in a couple of lines, with line 4, below, containing everything but the country and state.  Is there any way I can make only certain fields in that line ready only?  Specifically everything but the First and last name, and the email.

Thank you, in advance.

**Edit:** I should also add that AngularJS gives me headaches and raises my blood pressure, so if the answer involves directives or some crazy angular stuff please be nice.

```html
<div class="row-fluid" ng-repeat="field in delivery.RecipientsFields" 
     ng-hide="delivery.HideForDeliveryMethod() == 'true'">
    <div ng-class="{true : 'span8', false : 'span4'}[['AddressLine1', 'AddressLine2', 'AddressLine3','Email','PhoneNumber1'].indexOf(field._ServerTag) != -1]" 
         ng-show="field._Visible == 'true' || (field._ServerTag == 'RoomNumber' && delivery.showRoomNumberFieldForDeliveryMethod())">
        <label for="" ng-class="getRequiredClass(field._Required)" 
               ng-if="field._ServerTag != 'VATNumber' && field._ServerTag != 'RoomNumber'">{{field._DisplayName}}:</label>
        <!-- <label ng-show="field._Required">*</label> -->
        <input id="txt{{field._ServerTag + delivery.OrderAddressId}}"
               ng-if="field._ServerTag != 'VATNumber' && field._ServerTag != 'State_Province_Region' && field._ServerTag != 'Country' && field._ServerTag != 'RoomNumber'" 
               ng-model="field._FieldValue" type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="" class="span12" 
               value="{{field._FieldValue}}"
               ng-validate="{{field.Validate}}"
               ng-disabled="(delivery.DisableDeliveryAddressEdit_current && !IsRecipientFromAddressBook) || (delivery.DisableDeliveryAddressEdit_current && IsRecipientFromAddressBook && (!delivery.EnableChangingPersonNameOfaLockedAddress || (field._ServerTag != 'Email' && field._ServerTag != 'FirstName' && field._ServerTag != 'LastName' && field._ServerTag != 'MiddleName'))) || (delivery.useDedicatedAddressBook() && field._ServerTag != 'Email' && field._ServerTag != 'FirstName' && field._ServerTag != 'LastName' && field._ServerTag != 'MiddleName' && field._ServerTag != 'PhoneNumber1')" 
               maxlength="{{field._MaxCharacterLength}}" 
               readonly />

        <input id="txt{{field._ServerTag + delivery.OrderAddressId}}" 
               ng-if="field._ServerTag == 'State_Province_Region'"
               ng-hide="delivery.RecipientCountry.length && (field._DataSource | filter : {_OtherDataSourceKeys : delivery.RecipientCountry}).length" 
               ng-model="delivery.RecipientState_Province_Region" type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="" class="span12" 
               value="{{field._FieldValue}}" 
               ng-validate="{{field.Validate}}" 
               ng-disabled="delivery.DisableDeliveryAddressEdit_current || delivery.useDedicatedAddressBook()" 
               maxlength="{{field._MaxCharacterLength}}" 
               readonly />
        <select id="ddl{{field._ServerTag + delivery.OrderAddressId}}" 
                ng-if="field._ServerTag == 'Country'" 
                ng-model="delivery.RecipientCountry" 
                ng-options="option._Key as option._DisplayValue for option in field._DataSource" class="span12" 
                ng-change="CountryChanged(delivery)" 
                ng-disabled="delivery.DisableDeliveryAddressEdit_current || delivery.useDedicatedAddressBook()" 
                readonly >
        </select>
        <select id="ddl{{field._ServerTag + delivery.OrderAddressId}}" 
                ng-if="field._ServerTag == 'State_Province_Region'" 
                ng-show="delivery.RecipientCountry.length && (field._DataSource | filter : {_OtherDataSourceKeys : delivery.RecipientCountry}).length" 
                ng-model="delivery.RecipientState_Province_Region" 
                ng-options="option._Key as option._DisplayValue for option in field._DataSource | filter : {_OtherDataSourceKeys : delivery.RecipientCountry}" 
                class="span12" 
                ng-disabled="delivery.DisableDeliveryAddressEdit_current || delivery.useDedicatedAddressBook()" 
                ng-validate="{{field.Validate}}" 
                readonly >
         </select>
                    
        <label for="" ng-class="getRequiredClass(true)" ng-if="field._ServerTag == 'RoomNumber' && (field._Visible == 'true' || delivery.showRoomNumberFieldForDeliveryMethod())">{{field._DisplayName}}:</label>
        <input id="txt{{field._ServerTag + delivery.OrderAddressId}}" 
               ng-if="field._ServerTag == 'RoomNumber' && (field._Visible == 'true' || delivery.showRoomNumberFieldForDeliveryMethod())" 
               ng-model="field._FieldValue" type="text" 
               name="" placeholder="" class="span12" 
               value="{{field._FieldValue}}" 
               ng-validate="{{field.Validate}}"
               maxlength="{{field._MaxCharacterLength}}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: The fields in question]

Comment: How would I use this to only make the specific fields I want readonly?  I used "readonly" at the ends of the 4th line and it worked but made everything readonly.

Comment: **You need to do some basic debugging of your code.** To isolate the cause of the control becoming disabled, remove attributes until the control starts working, then add back attributes one by one. Once you know which attibute is causing the problem, isolate the term in the expression that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `<select>` element does not support the `readonly` attribute. Instead, use the `disabled` attribute for `<select>` elements.

For more information, see

- [MDN HTML Attributes Reference -- `readonly` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/readonly)
- [MDN HTML Attributes Reference -- `disabled` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled)
- [MDN HTML Elements Reference -- `<select>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)

Comment: Yes, I realized that afterwards, I modified the already existing ng-disabled to do that.  But my problem is that I am getting all fields readonly, and I need to have Email, first name, and last name still editable.